# Duration of Recurring Tasks in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, tasks

I have set up a recurring task to recur every 4 weeks for 4 occurrences. To me, this means the duration should be 4 x 4 x 7 = 112 days, but the duration is set to 253 days. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

The recurring task duration is not the sum of the durations of the detail tasks.  It is the span of working time from the start of the earliest of the details to the end of the last.